# Kronecker product

Tags: matrix

I have a problem,
I want to compute kronecker product as given below;

```
rho1 = MatrixForm[KroneckerProduct[{{1}, {0}}, {{1, 0}}]]; 
rho2 = MatrixForm[KroneckerProduct[{{1}, {0}}, {{1, 0}}]]; 
rho3 = MatrixForm[KroneckerProduct[{{1}, {0}}, {{1, 0}}]]; 
rho = MatrixForm[KroneckerProduct[rho1, rho2, rho3]]
```

and I get

```
MatrixForm[KroneckerProduct[MatrixForm[{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}], 
MatrixForm[{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}], MatrixForm[{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}]]]
```

Why the ouput not evaluate the kroneckerproduct and become a single matrix

Comment: `MatrixForm` is something used for printing. Never use it in calculations, or define variables with it.

Comment: what @MariusLadegårdMeyer is saying , `rho1 = KroneckerProduct[{{1}, {0}}, {{1, 0}}]` and likewise. After you evaluate `rho`, use `MatrixForm[rho]` to see how it looks.

Comment: ok. thanks. I try it and get the result. thank you again for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do want `MatrixForm`, then do it in this way.

```
(rho1 = KroneckerProduct[{{1}, {0}}, {{1, 0}}]) // MatrixForm
(rho2 = KroneckerProduct[{{1}, {0}}, {{1, 0}}]) // MatrixForm
(rho3 = KroneckerProduct[{{1}, {0}}, {{1, 0}}]) // MatrixForm
(rho = KroneckerProduct[rho1, rho2, rho3]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for suggestion coding. I will used it.